# Python извлечение данных из файлов .docx

Tags: python, pandas, ms-word

Есть 5000 заключений в формате .doxs.
Нужно из этих заключений вытащить определенные данные (Город, сумма, номер акта, дату) и сложить все в таблицу. Т.е. нужно создать базу этих заключений, на основании указанных в них данных. Просматривать каждый файл возможно, но очень долго )
Возможно ли какими то библиотеками Python реализовать такое?

Более менее разобралась с этим, на выходе получаю данные в виде:

```
[['4621'], ['17', 'января', '2020'], ['7618'], ['Алматы'], ['1000'], ['VU-KZ1317A'], ['не', 'связано']]
[['5829'], ['06', 'мая', '2020'], ['7782'], ['Караганда'], ['1000'], ['VU-KZ1317A'], ['однозначно', 'связано']]
[['4220'], ['13', 'декабря', '2019'], ['9569'], ['Махамбет'], ['2200'], ['MSM-KZ112'], ['не', 'связано']]
[['4337'], ['23', 'декабря', '2019'], ['855'], ['Кустанай'], ['1000'], ['VU-KZ1317A'], ['не', 'связано']]
[['2932'], ['06', 'сентября', '2019'], ['963'], ['Павлодар'], ['1000'], ['VU-KZ1317AF'], ['не', 'связано']]
[['2922'], ['05', 'сентября', '2019'], ['9934'], ['Махамбет'], ['5200'], ['MSM-KZ1129AF0'], ['не', 'связано']]
```

Туплю, конечно, но не могу сообразить как теперь это сложить в датафрейм.

[image: Вот такая табличка]

```
import docx2txt
import re
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
import pandas as pd

file = docx2txt.process("E:/тех.закл/Техническое заключение 81344 .от 05.01.20.docx")
file1 = re.sub(r'[;,\s]',' ', file)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Номер акта', 'Дата', 'Номер терминала', 'Город', 'Сумма', 'Модель'])
result = re.findall(r'к акту (\d+) |от (\d+ \w+\s+\d+)  года |по терминалу № (\d+).|\(г.(\w+)\).|в сумме (\d+).| модель (\w+-\w+).| (\w+\s+\w+\s+)с ошибками купюроприемного устройства.', file1)
result2 = [' '.join(i).split() for i in result]
res = [' ' + ' '.join(j) for j in result2]
df1 = df.append(res)
print(df1)
```

Получаю:

```
                  0 Город Дата Модель Номер акта Номер терминала Сумма
0              4324   NaN  NaN    NaN        NaN             NaN   NaN
1   23 декабря 2019   NaN  NaN    NaN        NaN             NaN   NaN
2             81344   NaN  NaN    NaN        NaN             NaN   NaN
3            Алматы   NaN  NaN    NaN        NaN             NaN   NaN
4              5000   NaN  NaN    NaN        NaN             NaN   NaN
5       VU-KZ1317AF   NaN  NaN    NaN        NaN             NaN   NaN
```

Т.е. полученный лист у меня заполняется столбцом, а не строкой как нужно.

Comment: Все заключения сделаны по шаблону? Или там «свободный» текст? В любом случае для того чтобы понять задачу понадобятся примеры входных данных (docx файлов) и результат, который вы хотите получить

Comment: Без открытия файлов никак. Вопрос лишь в том, как именно их прочесть - нативными средствами python или через экземпляр приложения Word. Сразу скажу, что нативно парсить доки - то еще развлечение. Да и автоматизировать извлечение данных из MS Office лучше средствами VBA или Microsoft.Office.Interop - здесь на выбор, что ближе. Если все же нужен именно питон, то лучше смотреть на решения на базе pywin32 - управления приложением через COM-порт.

Comment: К вопросу о том, что читать 5000 документов - это долго. Насколько долго? Как часто предполагается это делать? Если это разовая задача, и в дальнейшем вам нужно будет только дополнять данную базу 1-10 документами за раз, то время выполнения меньше 1 недели - приемлемый вариант, так как примерно в это же время можно обработать этот объем документации вручную.

Comment: Все заключения по одному шаблону. Из определенных строк нужно выдернуть значения и сложить. Я уже нашла, что python-docx читает и нужны регулярные выражения.

Comment: Все заключения по одному шаблону.
Уже нашла, что нужна python-docx и регулярны выражения.

Текст из которого нужно вытащить:
(В адрес сектора программирования поступил на рассмотрение акт недостачи денежных средств № 7855  от 24 ноября  2020 (г.Шымкент) в сумме 5000 тенге, возникших при выемке средств из терминала №  24380)
Отсюда выдернуть номер акта, дату ,город, сумму и номер терминала. Плюс еще дальше по тексту нужно выдернуть результат проверки.

Comment: Повторюсь - в таких вопросах должны присутствовать ссылки на примеры входных файлов (2-3 файла) и пример результирующего фрейма в ответе. __NOTE:__ Конфиденциальные данные лучше предварительно заменить на нейтральный текст.